# Create a dynamic Lookup Column in SharePoint List New Item page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, project

We have 4 lists, List Parent and List Child A, Child B and Child C. List Parent has column "Project Name" and "Portfolio Name". All the child Lists use the Project Name column from the Parent. However, we need to narrow down the results for each Child list based on the Portfolio Name. For Example,

Child List A is only associated to Portfolio X

Child list B is only associated to Portfolio Y

Child List C is only associated to Portfolio Z

I want to narrow down the Project Name column to show only those entries as required. Is there any way that I can do this by JavaScript or JQuery ?

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can display other columns from an associated item through an existing lookup column connection.

If you edit the Project Name lookup columns in the child lists, you should see checkboxes for other columns in the parent list that you have the option of displaying in the child list. Click the checkbox next to Portfolio Name to pull that field along.